# Qual é a melhor tradução para "slot filling" ou "semantic slot filling"?

Tags: tradução, tradução-inglês

Estou trabalhando na tradução de um curso de NLP e me deparei com o termo: **"Semantic Slot Filling"**.

Eu só conheço esse termo no inglês e não sei se existe uma tradução técnica para esse termo (utilizada em artigos), ou se ele é sempre utilizado em inglês mesmo.

Comment: Por favor, você poderia explicar o que é "semantic slot filling" e "slot filling"? Conhecer os termos em sua amplitude pode ajudar bastante na tradução.

Comment: Evite abreviações, aqui temos pessoas mais técnicas, mas é necessário o mínimo de contexto para que possam te ajudar.

Comment: Encontrei em um artigo "extração de parâmetros".

Comment: Davy, na minha opinião, algum tradutor em algum lugar vai traduzir ou já traduziu o têrmo. Eu não entendo como o pessoal faz doutorado e não conseguem traduzir esse tipo de coisa. Olha só aqui: https://www.inesc-id.pt/ficheiros/publicacoes/7383.pdf

Comment: Eis uma boa explicação: https://www.rose-hulman.edu/class/cs/archive/other-old/archive/fall14/schedule/day23/SlotGrammars.pdf Seria um bom lugar para começar: • Slots can be viewed as names for syntactic roles of phrases in
a sentence.
• They later on assist in extracting information.

Answer (score 5):

Após uma busca extensiva no Google, não encontrei uma tradução exata de ambos os termos.

Então, traduzi de acordo com três trabalhos acadêmicos da área:

> **Slot filling** → *Slot-filling*, Preenchimento de lacunas, Preenchimento de *slots*

Antes de escolher uma tradução, pense no seu leitor. Qual tradução ele compreenderá mais facilmente?

Você pode deixar os termos *slot* e *slot filling* no inglês mesmo, já que podem ser mais conhecidos assim.

> **Semantic slot filling** → Preenchimento semântico de *slots*, Preenchimento semântico de lacunas

Como termo técnico não dicionarizado no português brasileiro, escreve-se *slot* e *slot filling* em itálico.

**Fontes**

SPECIA, L.; RINO, L. H. M. **Representação Semântica**: Alguns Modelos Ilustrativos. Série de Relatórios do Núcleo Interinstitucional de Lingüística (NILC). 2002. Disponível em: http://wiki.icmc.usp.br/images/1/1c/SpeciaRino2002.pdf. Acesso em: 01 jan. 2019.

PINHEIRO, V.; PEQUENO, T.; FURTADO, V. Um Analisador Semântico Inferencialista de Sentenças em Linguagem Natural. **Linguamática**, v. 2, n. 1, p. 111-130, 7 abr. 2010. Disponível em: http://www.linguamatica.com/index.php/linguamatica/article/view/49. Acesso em: 01 jan. 2019.

SANTIAGO, C. S. F.  **A construção causal-explicativa (por + sn + de + x) em perspectiva funcional**. 2017. 85 f. Dissertação (Mestrado em Estudos da Linguagem) - Programa de Pós-Graduação em Estudos da Linguagem, Universidade Federal do Rio Grande do Norte (UFRN), Natal, 2017. Disponível em: https://repositorio.ufrn.br/jspui/handle/123456789/23991. Acesso em: 01 jan. 2019.

Answer (score 1):

"Preenchimento de compartimentos semânticos"
"Preenchimento de compartimentos"

Outras formas de tradução da palavra "slot" como entalhe, ranhura, encaixe, abertura, janela, vão, são inadequadas.

A palavra "semântico" é bastante objetiva e adequada para o uso.